# Magento 2.2.7 dashboard logos and images are not displaying

Tags: magento2.2.7

In the dashboard images and logos are not displaying????even magento logo also not displaying???can anyone help with it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> You should run `static-content:deploy` after running `setup:upgrade` :
>   **`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`**